# Spring boot application can't make http requests once deployed, but it works locally

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I'm working on a Spring Boot application and I'm currently facing a problem trying to send http requests to external web services (specifically, the URLs are these ones: https://dgidb.org/api/v2/interactions.json?genes= and https://api.pharmgkb.org/v1/data/clinicalAnnotation?location.genes.symbol=, obviously with the correct params, for example 'FLT4').

I have a rest controller with some methods mapped to get requests, each of which makes another request to a web service. When our frontend calls one of the APIs, the backend calls one of the above web services and the resulting json is then serialized via Jackson ObjectMapper and sent to our frontend as usual.

It works flawlessly on my machine, but it doesn't at all once deployed on a server running Ubuntu.
In fact, when called by the frontend, it gives error 500 and CORS Missing Allow Origin error. To make sure it wasn't an implementation-related issue, I and my colleague tried different implementations of the above methods, using WebClient (WebFlux) as well as RestTemplate and even curl; we also tried using the annotation `@CorsOrigin(origins = "*")` and even adding manually the annotation "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to the resulting ResponseEntity, but the result is the same: it doesn't work on the deployed application.

The logs produced on the server are the following:

Curl implementation:

```
Forwarding to error page from request [/endpoint_name] due to exception [No content to map due to end-of-input at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 0]] com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 0]
```

RestTemplate:

```
.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://api.pharmgkb.org/v1/data/clinicalAnnotation": Connection timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

WebClient:

```
.ErrorPageFilter [https-openssl-nio-8443-exec-57] Forwarding to error page from request [/endpoint_name] due to exception [Timeout on blocking read for 30000000000 NANOSECONDS] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 30000000000 NANOSECONDS
```

All the other APIs in our application work as expected, the problem shows only with the ones which call the above external web services.

Here's a code example:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/controller_path")
public class MyController {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @GetMapping("/api_endpoint")
    public ResponseEntity<PharmGKB> getPharmGKBDrugs(@RequestParam(name = "gene") String gene) throws Exception {
    
        final String uri =
            "https://api.pharmgkb.org/v1/data/clinicalAnnotation?location.genes.symbol=" + gene.toUpperCase();
        final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String responseBody;

        try {
        
            final ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
                    .exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
            responseBody = response.getBody();

        } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
            responseBody = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
        }

        final PharmGKB pharmGKB = objectMapper.readValue(responseBody, PharmGKB.class);

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        ResponseEntity<PharmGKB> response = new ResponseEntity<>(pharmGKB, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Please, could you help me solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Apparently you cannot connect from the server to that URL. There is probably some firewall blocking that traffic. Also your code is flawed, don't recreate a `RestTemplate` you should use the `RestTemplateBuilder` to create one and inject it. Instead of a `String` directly request the `PharmGKB` object and remove the `ObjectMapper` the `RestTemplate` will take care of that.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, I didn't spend much time optimizing the code since our main version of the api was using WebClient and I made the RestTemplate and the curl version only to see if the problem was related to the methods' implementation. I too think that there must be something on the server/firewall/proxy, but I must point out that I can call those external APIs via curl on the server. So, if there is a block, it has an effect (only) on our application but not on the whole system. Could it be related to the port number the application is using for Tomcat?